# Game goes to GameOver when act is done

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

I have a simple swipe game - when there is right arrow displayed, the user should swipe right (and also for other directions). This is my code (its just repeating itself so I will post only one direction):

```
if (left && frameCounterLeft <= maxFrames && isLeftNow)
{
    //Reset the other directions
    right = false;
    up = false;
    down = false;
    tap = false;

    //First time
    if (frameCounterLeft == 0)
        ThrowLeft(true);
    else
        ThrowLeft(false);

    //Animation
    frameCounterLeft++;

    //End animation
    if (frameCounterLeft == maxFrames)
    {
        ClonePlayer();
        frameCounterLeft = 0;

    }
}
else if (left && frameCounterLeft == 0 && !isLeftNow)
{
    GameOver();
}
```

The TheowLeft method:

```
void ThrowLeft(bool FirstTime)
{
    if (FirstTime)
    {
        UpdateScore();
        left = false;
    }
    player.transform.Translate(new Vector3(player.transform.position.x - throwVelocity, 0));
    player.transform.Rotate(0, throwVelocity * 5, 0);
}
```

The UpdateScore method:

```
void UpdateScore()
{ 
    score++;
    if (currentTimeLimit - timeLeft <= 0.5f * currentTimeLimit && ultraMeter.value < 35)
        ultraMeter.value++;

    if (score % ultraMeter.maxValue == 0)
        currentTimeLimit = 0.9f * currentTimeLimit;

    timeLeft = currentTimeLimit;
    if(ultraMeter.value == ultraMeter.maxValue)
        ultraReady = true;
}
```

left/right/up/down = user input left/right/up/down swipe - working (checked) tap = if user taps the screen - working (checked) framesCounterLeft = for the animation to be couple frames isLeftNow = if the left arrow is displayed right now - working (checked)

GameOver() is called when I am doing any swipe (even if its a right  swipe).
e.g - There is left arrow displayed. When I swipe left (or any other direction) GameOver() is called. I want it to be called only if the swipe is wrong (e.g there is left card right now and I am swiping right/down/up or I am tapping)

Please help me I want to continue developing this game.

Comment: It's not clear in your question what your problem is - please clarify.

Comment: @auburg Is it clear now?

Comment: Please add the part where you handle the input and set the directions. Otherwise it will be hard to say more than that your conditions are messed up.

Comment: This is a pretty good case of learning to debug, though from the looks of this if - else if .. this is getting called in a loop most likely? at the end of the animation you set left to false, and then set frameCounterLeft to 0, im assuming that something is also then setting isLeftNow to false, and then the loop is being called again, causing it to go into the game over clause.. though the code posted doesnt show enough to say that for sure

Comment: @GunnarB. It`s not my input detenction. It`s prefect I tested it. Just added more code it will be very nice from you to look at it

Comment: @Gibbon I added more code please see if you can help in anyway

Comment: @DanielOhayon in your first block of code though, you are incrementing a value, so im guessing that block is inside of a loop of some form? would be good to see the loop that its in to see if it is an issue in there

Comment: What I meant is not the actual input detection, but instead the values you set based on that. For example, why do you need the reset directions part at the beginning of the block? If you don't set those to true, you shouldn't need those.

Comment: @Gibbon yes, it`s inside the Update() method that is called every frame (I`m programming with Unity)

Comment: Without seeing how you're getting input and the rest of your if..else if..else if.. chain, my guess is that your "swipe" is being detected as a tap, and that's wrong, so you fail. You need to go through basic debugging to figure out which if-statement is generating the wrong result.